# how can i exec to create a global class object

Tags: python, function, class, global-variables

I'm trying to create a function to automate creating class objects but the variables storing them are local variables i've tried using `globals()` but its giving me a different error

```
items_created = 0


class Item:
    def __init__(self, name: str, price: float, quantity=0):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.quantity = quantity
        print(f"'{self.name}' was added")

    def total_amount(self):
        print(self.price * self.quantity)


def create_item():
    num = input("number of items being added: ")
    num = int(num)
    global items_created
    items_created += num
    for x in range(num):
        while True:
            u, y, c = input("name, price, quantity: ").split()
            assert int(y) >= 0
            assert int(c) >= 0
            exec(f"it{items_created} = Item(str(u), float(y), int(c))", globals())
            unique = input("Y/N: ")
            if unique == "Y":
                unique_attr = input("unique attribute: ")
                exec(f"it{items_created}.has_{unique_attr}= True")
                break
            else:
                break

create_item()
print(it1)
```

i think the problem is this line `exec(f"it{items_created} = Item(str(u), float(y), int(c))", globals())` without globals() when i print it1 its not defined when i do the value of u is not defined

Comment: Don't use dynamic variables and attributes. Use lists and dictionaries instead.

Comment: the error with `exec` can be fix by adding the `locals()` parameter as well, so `exec("...", globals(), locals())` . Then, after some user interaction, it will give raise to another error but I did not read the program carefully, `NameError: name 'it1' is not defined
`. Hope it help

Comment: yeah thanks i used a list instead